# STL list out of range in the first push_back

Tags: c++, stl

I used STL list in my win32 program, which run into a weird problem. To be specific, I got an `out of range` runtime error on the first time the list did a `push_back()`.

Here's the declaration of this list instance:

```
AtomActionList g_AtomActions[MAXPLAYER];
```

It's a global variable and in the same file with `_tWinMain()` entry.

Here's the related defines (they are separated in 3 different header files):

```
#define MAXPLAYER 2

typedef int AtomAction_id;

typedef std::list<AtomAction_id> AtomActionList;
```

And here's the parts that ever use g_AtomActions in the main file:

```
...

g_AtomActions[_i].push_back(aaid);

...

if (!g_AtomActions[_i].empty()){
    shareData.newAtomAction[_i] = g_AtomActions[_i].front();
    g_AtomActions[_i].pop_front();
}
```

There used to be a clear method in an init function but I commented it out when I saw the runtime "out of range" error in the `g_AtomActions[_i].push_back(aaid);` part. However, the error remains after that.

I've set some breakpoints and run it in debug mode and watch. I'm quite sure the error happens in the first time `g_AtomActions[_i].push_back(aaid);` is executed. `_i` is 0 and `aaid` is 2, size of `g_AtomActions[_i]` is 0. No other parts have ever used this identifier yet.

I failed to figure out why. So I tried to change it to deque, hoped to get some luck, and unexpectedly found the `g_AtomActions[_i].push_back(aaid);` works in my program (but errored  again in another part which used list).

Could someone give a possible explanation?

Comment: Please show how you are iterating through the array of lists.

Comment: @Jesse I don't do that. I only use `push_back()` and `pop_front()` and `empty()` so far. The error occurs in the `push_back()` part.

Comment: You have an array of list ? why can't it be list<AtomActionList>. my comment does not really address the issue though.

Comment: It sounds like UB at work. The place you're seeing the problem probably isn't the root cause. It's hard to tell from the code you presented. All we can really do is guess and speculate.

Comment: @jagansai I need randomly access to the array of g_AtomActions and I won't do any insertion or deletion to it, so I use the array of list. Could there be anything wrong?

Comment: @VictorT. Not actual work stuff but similar. I don't know how could this happen and how to figure it out. And I can't just give all the code in the program (it's pretty much). Any possible explanation would be helpful to me.

Comment: Since details are scarce I can only guess. One possibility is that you're up against the static initialization fiasco. Another is that you have some other UB somewhere. By the way, identifiers with leading underscore are reserved in the global namespace, in C++ constants are defined with `const` not with `#define` (and don't then have all uppercase names), `tWinMain` is a Microsoft monstrosity that buys you nothing (but trouble) and should be replaced with standard `main`, and generally, *global variables are Very Bad™*, mainly because of the spaghetti information-flow.

Comment: @AlfP.Steinbach Thank you. It really helps. Global variables are very bad. Some classes failed to initialize but never telled me anything until I use pointers to `new` them in another init function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to hints from @AlfP, this problem is finally resolved by me.

Global variables are very bad. Some classes failed to initialize but never telled me anything until I use pointers to `new` them in another init function.

Answer (score 1):

Your global variable initialization is missing from your code. If you're really biting off STL for this, you may have declared it to be a `vector<>`, and if it is, there are not "lists" in there yet unless you explicitly constructed them to have such. Since it is indexed by variable in you're code (_i) I'm assuming the array of lists is dynamic. If this is the case, you need a list in your array first, and it is likely there that the index oo-range is begin thrown.

```
typedef std::list<int> IntegerList;
typedef std::vector<IntegerList> ArrayOfIntegerLists;
ArrayOfIntegerLists g_ArrayofLists(10);
```

If yours looks like this:

```
ArrayOfIntegerLists g_ArrayofLists;
```

You have no actual lists in there yet. Perhaps add one, or maybe check `.size()` against your index to ensure you're not 'going off the deep end' so to speak.